# jQuery AJAX call always firing success

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have this login form in which I do a server side validation and now I'm trying to do a jQuery validation.

the form snippet:

```
<div class="form-actions">
     <button type="submit" class="btn green pull-right">Login <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i></button>
</div>
```

jQuery snippet: (I use bootstrap's login.js)

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    var un = $('#usernameEmail').val();
    var p = $('#pass').val();

    $.ajax({
        url:  '/admin/checkIfUsernameOrEmailExists',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {un: un, pass: p},
        success: function(data){
            form.submit();
         },
        error: function(data){
            alert("Error");
        }    
    });  
  }
```

the function `checkIfUsernameOrEmailExists` is working perfectly. I do a `console.log(data)` on success function (because it's always firing) and data is false when It has to be false, and true when has to be true. So given this situation I'm confused about where the mistake might be.

**EDIT**

I tried this before with no success, now I know for sure that in theory it's correct as Ramesh and Keune suggested... but is still not working, perhaps I have something wrong and don't realize? No errors are displayed, no log in `console.log` and no alert showing up.

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
     var un = $('#usernameEmail').val();
     var p = $('#pass').val();
     $.ajax({
        url:  '/admin/checkIfUsernameOrEmailExists',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {un: un, pass: p},
        success: function(data){
            if (data) {
                form.submit()
            }else{
                // console.log(data);
                alert(data);
            };
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("Error");
        }    
        });  
       }
```

**SOLUTION**

As Blurfus said, I was missing the "" so, inside success function the data comparison should be against a string:

```
success: function(data){
    if (data == "true") {
        form.submit()
    }else{
        alert(data);
    };
},
```

Comment: success function is called when the request is successful. it doesn't know anything about your business logic.

Comment: @keune I know now. Thanks for the tip. Anyways as I was telling RameshKotha it works when its success and user can login. But if it's wrong, the alert msge is not showing up

Comment: if `data` is an object or an array, or anything truethy (such as the *string* `"false"`), it will submit the form.

Comment: @KevinB really? and what is the correct way of showing when it's false? :s

Comment: returning a json string representation of an object that has a flag, such as `{ "success": false }` and then setting the dataType to json. `if (data.success) { do stuff }` alternatively you could have your server return a non-2xx status code.

Comment: Why are you passing in the password when you check if the username/email exists?

Comment: @KevinB bc I have a function that receives both parameters, but I think I will just add another one to check only the username

Comment: it just seemed odd. If passing in the password, you might aswell skip the check and just submit the form, and do the check there. or skip submitting the form and do the action on this ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), you need to do this in your `success` callback function

```
success: function(data, status, jqXHR){
   ...
}
```

Yes, I know the other two are optional but according to the function signature:

`Function(PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )`

`Data` is an object returned from the server, formatted according to the `dataType` parameter (which you have not specified) and which possible values are `xml, json, script, or html` - However, it does try to use an intelligent guess. So, in other words, it does not handle boolean as `data` very well (at all?).

My best guess is that you will have to check against a `String` like:

```
if(data == "TRUE"){
    form.submit();
}else{
    alert('Error');
}
```

and maybe specify a `dataType` parameter in addition as well.

Comment: hey thanks for the comment. It worked with what Ramesh and Keune said, t o put the logic inside success function. But thanks to you I found the problem was that I was missing de "" in the line: if(data == "TRUE")

Answer (score 1):

I think your checkIfUsernameOrEmailExists is just returning TRUE or FALSE. if it throws any error then only jquery error will be called. Other wise it will goes to success only. If you want to throw error, put a check for false in success and alert it.

```
$.ajax({
        url:  '/admin/checkIfUsernameOrEmailExists',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {un: un, pass: p},
        success: function(data){
            if(data){
               form.submit();
            }else{
               alert('Error');
            }
         },
        error: function(data){
            alert("Error");
        }    
    });
```

Refer : [JQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Ramesh is right. The jQuery check for success is if the AJAX query went successfully or not. The data you receive back is irrelevant.

Comment: I did this before and I erased it because it didn't work for me. I know this is the correct logic, but this code for me is not working. Alert error is still not showing up, what can it be?

Comment: put console.log of data and see, what is coming, is coming as false or not?

Comment: @RameshKotha console.log works only when it's true, when it's false it doesn't. This is weird, also no erros appear

Comment: if you have firebug, it definitely shows the error.

Comment: @RameshKotha I do inspect it (I have chrome) but no error appears :s

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56727/discussion-between-ramesh-kotha-and-limon).